# A/B Testing Data by Day

Tags: content-testing

I realize this may be an odd request, but our Marketing department really wants to get A/B Testing Data per day. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this. Is this something that I'd be able to find within Sitecore? Even if I have to pull raw data and massage it, that's fine, I just have no idea where to start with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this specifically, but I suspect you could find what you're looking for by inspecting the Analytics database's tables.

You can find out the server and database name by looking in your connection strings for the `reporting` connection string.

[image: analytics database table list]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dan. I haven't had a chance to look at the database directly yet, but I suspect this may be the best way to reach this data. I'll update this as soon as I get a chance to dig in.